# MySQL error 1452 (23000) cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

This is what I entered for the tables

```
mysql> create table A6M351kjp.Claim (ClaimID INT (10) NOT NULL, VIN INT (10) NOT NULL, ClaimDate DateTime Null, ClaimStatus VarChar(45) Null, Primary Key (ClaimID));
```

added foreign key here

```
mysql> alter table A6M351kjp.Claim add foreign key (VIN) references Car(VIN);
```

enter data

```
mysql> insert into A6M351kjp.Claim (ClaimID, VIN, ClaimDate, ClaimStatus) values (101, 901, '2014-01-01', 'Open');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`A6M351kjp`.`Claim`, CONSTRAINT `Claim_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`VIN`) REFERENCES `Car` (`VIN`))
```

what is cause of this error and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It is all in the error message - a foreign key constraint fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

901 doesn't exist in the Car table. As it is referenced as foreign key, needs to be there in the parent table.